# which sentence is correct: "Ella and Rosy were absent in today's class." OR "Ella and Rosy were absent from today's class."

Tags: prepositions

which sentence is correct:  "Ella and Rosy were absent in today's class." OR "Ella and Rosy were absent from today's class."

Answer (score 1):

"Absent from" is more idiomatic in that context. "Absent in" occurs too, but in other contexts.

Here is a link to show the relative frequency of the two prepositions, with samples of the uses in books:

[Google Ngram viewer "absent from, absent in"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=absent%20in%2C%20absent%20from&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cabsent%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabsent%20from%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cabsent%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabsent%20from%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Thanks A Lot!!!